# postfix verify command not running and seems to be delaying mail by 3 seconds?

Tags: postfix, smtp

I've been noticing that my postfix SMTP transactions seem to pause for 3 seconds in the middle.  In looking at my SMTP trace logs I see the following:

```
2021-03-17 00:19:54,869 TRACE SmtpClientImpl - wrote MAIL FROM <foo@...>
2021-03-17 00:19:54,869 TRACE SmtpClientImpl - read MAIL FROM response 250 2.1.0 Ok
2021-03-17 00:19:54,869 TRACE SmtpClientImpl - wrote RCPT TO <bar@...>
--- NOTE: ~3 second gap here ---
2021-03-17 00:19:57,871 INFO  SmtpHandler - 38:1615954066423: rcpt address foo@...
2021-03-17 00:19:57,872 TRACE SmtpClientImpl - read RCPT TO response 250 2.1.5 Ok
2021-03-17 00:19:57,872 TRACE SmtpClientImpl - wrote DATA start
2021-03-17 00:19:57,872 TRACE SmtpClientImpl - read DATA response 354 End data with ...
```

Everything else goes through in 0-3 milliseconds but the `RCPT TO` command takes 3 *seconds* to respond.

For a long time I thought my code was at fault but now I wonder if my ~new installation of Postfix is not configured correctly.  I find mention of a `verify` process but I never see that process running and I'm wondering if it is at fault.  I also see mentions of `address_verify_poll_delay` (default `3s`) and `address_verify_poll_count` in the postfix docs which seem to indicate that an address is verified by the `verify` process while the mailer waits to check an address.

I have the following in my `/etc/postfix/master.cf`

```
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
```

However, I never see this application running and the `address_verify_map` setting points to a file that is not there.

- Any idea what I am missing here?
- Should I see a verify process?
- Any idea how to figure out why it is not starting?
- Is there some other validations that could explain this sort of delay?

Thanks much for any help.

Comment: Here http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html they say it's normal to have couple of secs delay. IIUC you have to enable verification, see the link.

Comment: Thanks @JiriB.  I've looked at that README but I'll look more closely again.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some other validations that could explain this sort of delay?

Maybe I was concentrating too much on verify because it turned out not to be the problem.  By default the `smtpd_client_restrictions` has the following value:

sleep 3, reject_unauth_pipelining

This means that after the `RCPT TO` command, postfix sleeps for 3 seconds to see if the client keeps on sending SMTP commands which would indicate some sort of stupid bot.  Yes, postfix is cool.  I changed this in the `main.cf` to be:

```
permit_mynetworks, sleep 3, reject_unauth_pipelining
```

The `permit_mynetworks` short circuits the restrictions and removed the sleep for clients connecting on the local networks including localhost.  I figured this out after turning on:

```
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
debug_peer_level = 3
```

This turned on a higher level of debugging when connecting from localhost.  Then in in the syslog logs I saw (along with a crap-ton of other log lines):

```
Mar 17 22:02:16 postfix/smtpd[19934]: < localhost[127.0.0.1]: RCPT TO:<foo@...>
...
Mar 17 22:02:16 postfix/smtpd[19934]: >>> START Client host RESTRICTIONS <<<
Mar 17 22:02:16 postfix/smtpd[19934]: generic_checks: name=sleep
--- NOTE the 3 second delay here ---                       ^^^^^
Mar 17 22:02:19 postfix/smtpd[19934]: generic_checks: name=sleep status=0
Mar 17 22:02:19 postfix/smtpd[19934]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_pipelining
```

It was pretty obvious then.  Postfix logging++.